# How to specify bash autocompletion on directories and files of certain extensions for a command?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a command `play` that takes files with extensions `mp4` or `mkv` as arguments.

I have created a file `play_completion.sh` in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`

I want to have the command `play` autocomplete directories and file names of extensions `mp4` or `mkv` only.  I have searched for help on this issue with no luck and the documentation for bash autocompletion is overwhelming.

I have this so far..

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(mp4|mkv)' play
```

but after I source it with `source /etc/bash_completion.d/play_completion.sh` it only autocompletes file names of the desired extensions and not directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add [`-o plusdirs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) auto-completion action to the command too, so that auto-completion will attempt to add directory name to the previous result (ignoring pattern match)

```
complete -f -o plusdirs -X '!*.@(mp4|mkv)' play
```

- `!` negate the completion, meaning that auto-competition will ignore completion result other than a matched pattern we specified `*.@(mp4|mkv)`;
- `@` telling auto-completion to match on at least one of the given patterns only; the `@(pattern-list)` is known as the Bash's Extended Glob. we can use `*.+(pattern-list)` glob as well here.

to force completion on both files &directories name for the `play` command and only and only expand for the given pattern do it like below:

```
complete -d -X '!*@(mp4|mkv)' -f -X '!*.@(mp4|mkv)' play
```

below should work too:

```
complete -d -f -X '!*.@(mp4|mkv)' play
```